# How to scrape paragraphs from websites using python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a question bank from this website

https://www.neetprep.com/questions/851-Botany/7918-Living-World?courseId=386

I am using the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import re

my_url = 'https://www.neetprep.com/questions/851-Botany/7918-Living-World?courseId=386'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class": "-PmH"})
print(soup.prettify(containers[0]))
```

My output is coming as:

```html
<span class="-PmH" id="questionUXVlc3Rpb246NzE3MQ==">
 <p>
  The third name in trinomial nomenclature is
 </p>
 <p>
  (1) Species
 </p>
 <p>
  (2) Subgenus
 </p>
 <p>
  (3) Subspecies
 </p>
 <p>
  (4) Ecotype
 </p>
</span>
```

Now how do I modify the code to get just the question and the options as my output text.

For this question my output should be

```
The third name in trinomial nomenclature is
(1) Species
(2) Subgenus
(3) Subspecies
(4) Ecotype
```

Hence I want to remove the `<p>` and `</p>` tags from my output.

Comment: you can use the get_text() method available in beautifulsoup. That will remove all HTML tags give you just the text.

Comment: `for p in containers[0].findAll('p'): print(p.text)`. You do not need to `prettify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change:

```
print(soup.prettify(containers[0]))
```

to

```
print(containers[0].text.split("\n"))
```

Comment: You don't even need to split on newlines

Comment: Just the containers[0].text  gave my desired output. Thanks a lot!